# Movie story leaps forward

Tags: word-usage

Can we use the following statement to mention the idea of leaping into the future:

> Then the story moved forward to an era which was around a century **ahead that time**.

My friend was describing the story of a movie and he used this statement. The complete description that he gave is as follows:

> The story revolved around the life of a princess. Then, the story moved forward to an era which was around a century ahead that time. It then discussed the story of the rebirth of that princess.

Comment: You could use "The story *jumped* forward 100 years, to an era where ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. If you use "that," you need to add an "of":

> ahead **of** that time

The following alternate ways to say roughly the same thing:

> ahead in time
>
> in the future
>
> into the future

The entire sentence is kind of clunky - I would personally rewrite it to:

> Then, the story advances a century into the future.

Or something similar. In it's current state, there are a lot of extra unnecessary words.